# "Wrong" access point is chosen

Tags: wifi

I have the problem that the RaspberryPi does not seem to select the best AP.

There are three APs available in my WLAN. `sudo iwlist wlan0 scan | egrep "Cell|ESSID|Signal|Channel|Rates"` returns:

```
      Cell 01 - Address: 60:31:97:FA:3B:A6
                Channel:3
                Frequency:2.422 GHz (Channel 3)
                Quality=29/70  Signal level=-81 dBm  
                ESSID:"Meins"
                Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
      Cell 07 - Address: 3C:37:12:10:64:A0
                Channel:11
                Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                Quality=57/70  Signal level=-53 dBm  
                ESSID:"Meins"
                Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
      Cell 08 - Address: E0:28:6D:63:EC:8B
                Channel:11
                Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                Quality=25/70  Signal level=-85 dBm  
                ESSID:"Meins"
                Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
```

So I would say Cell 07 on channel 11 has the best signal level.

But `sudo iwlist wlan0 channel` lists:

```
wlan0     12 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.422 GHz (Channel 3)
```

The current channel is 3, which isn't the best.

I've used `sudo iwconfig wlan0 ap auto` and `sudo iwconfig wlan0 channel auto` to configured automatic selection.

Is there anything I can check which may force channel 3 to be used?

### Edit

I've changed the channels to avoid having the same channel on two different APs.

Now, the raspberryPi sees:

```
      Cell 04 - Address: E0:28:6D:63:EC:8B
                Channel:11
                Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                Quality=36/70  Signal level=-74 dBm  
                ESSID:"Meins"
                Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
      Cell 07 - Address: 3C:37:12:10:64:A0
                Channel:6
                Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                Quality=47/70  Signal level=-63 dBm  
                ESSID:"Meins"
                Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
      Cell 12 - Address: 60:31:97:FA:3B:A6
                Channel:1
                Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                Quality=24/70  Signal level=-86 dBm  
                ESSID:"Meins"
                Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
```

However, channel 11 is now selected.
`Current Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)` :-/

Is there any logging I might want to activate to see more about the selection process?

### Another edit

Maybe it takes some time. I've checked once again and now channel 6 is used, which is the one I would expected.
`Current Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)`

Possibly the cause was that channel 11 was used by two APs.

Comment: maybe channel 3 is actually "best" ... depends on what  "best" really means

Comment: cell 07 and 08 are on the same channel - so, they would interfere with each other

Comment: @jsotola: Well, I would say a signal level of -53 dBm is better than -81 dBm.

Comment: @JaromandaX: So does the raspberryPi not select an AP, if there's another one on the same channel? Even if one is far better than the other?

Comment: No idea how the chosen channel is chosen

Comment: @JaromandaX: Too bad. ;-)

Comment: @D.Mika - so, in a roundabout way, I was correct!

Answer (score 0):

It actually seems that the cause was the duplicated channel. After reconfiguring the APs so that each transmits on its own channel, the Raspberry Pi has now chosen the strongest AP.